# Finding a balanced spanning tree

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

I am working on the following exercise:

> Consider an undirected connected graph $G(V,E)$ with edge weights $w_e$ for $e \in E$. Devise an efficient algorithm that finds a balanced spanning tree, that is a spanning tree that minimizes 
>   $$max_{e \in E_T} w_e - min_{e \in E_T}.$$

My approach is the following:

1. Check if $G$ is connected. If not stop.
2. Sort the edges in increasing order according to their edge weights.
3. Traverse the edges, starting from the smallest and add it to $T$ if it contains an unvisited vertex. Mark the newely visited vertices.

Is this correct?

Comment: Suppose you have the complete graph on 3 vertices. The edges have weight 1,9,10. So, you choose the first edge to be the 1 and the second edge to be the 9. However, this gives $$\operatorname{max}_{e\in E_T} w_e - \operatorname{min}_{e\in E_T} w_e = 9-1=8$$ If you had chosen the 9 and 10, you would have had $$\operatorname{max}_{e\in E_T} w_e - \operatorname{min}_{e\in E_T} w_e = 10-9 = 1$$ so your algorithm does not appear to always find the spanning tree that minimizes that formula.

Comment: This may be wrong, but is an idea: consider the maximum spanning tree and the minimum spanning tree--maybe the balanced one is one of these.

Comment: How about once you complete your spanning tree, you start a minimization process? It would begin 4. Suppose you remove the edge with the minimum weight. This will give you two connected components. 5. List all edges that can connect the two components with weight greater than the minimum weight edge that you remove. If no such edge exists, then stop, and the T you had was correct. Otherwise, try the next smallest edge to create a spanning tree $T'$. If $T'$ has a smaller span of maximum to minimum weight, choose it as your new $T$ and return to step 4.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe: I can see your intent, but how can we be sure that this indeed delivers a minimum of $max_{e \in E_T} w_e - min_{e \in E_T}$?

Comment: I am not sure. I was just offering a place to start investigating, not necessarily an answer.